# How to return a field as Nullable from a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server `View`, and It has a field like this `ISNULL(co.[MyValue],0) AS MyValue` in the select.

`MyValue` in its table is a *Nullable* field, now I want to return `0` if the value is null but keep the field *Nullable*.

I want this because I don't want to change the Entity Framework EDMX file which has this view field as Nullable field.

Is there a way to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try **COALESCE**

```
COALESCE(co.[MyValue],0)
```

Comment: Or ISNULL(co.[MyValue],0)     to see what's the difference between COALESCE() and ISNULL()  just visit: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN [MyValue] IS NULL THEN 0 
           ELSE [MyValue] 
       END
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, that I just used **`CASE WHEN`** here, and it is as simple as you can see, I don't think any other explanation will be needed here.

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN Table_Name .[MyValue] IS NULL THEN 0 
           ELSE Table_Name .[MyValue] 
       END
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: @shA.t i didn't notice that, i just answered him as per his requirement.
i don't need to follow anybody's answer.
Thank you.

Comment: @shA.t i modified my mistake of **co** Thanks for suggestion.